# Continued to vs Continuing

Tags: tense, verbs

Here are two examples from the news:

> 1. In July exports of goods *continued to* decline
> 2. Pregnant women *continuing to* drink alcohol despite warnings from medical experts

Whats the difference between using "*continued to*" and "*continuing*" in terms of time/tense?

Comment: I think this is Too Basic even for ELL. OP's first example is a normal ***sentence***. The second one is just a ***noun phrase*** with no functional verb.

Comment: I suppose it's possible that this question could give rise to a canonical answer expounding on the function of gerunds and/or differentiating [present progressive](http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/tenses/present_progressive.htm) and [simple past](http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/tenses/simple_past.htm) in fine detail. The question could definitely be improved with a little more detail on the specific nature of the confusion (assuming that it is, in fact, a bigger issue than a search for “[continued tense](https://www.google.com/search?q="continued"+tense)” could solve).

Comment: @Tyler: There might indeed be something to discuss if we were being asked about the difference between ***women*** and the possible alternative ***women's*** in OP's example #2 (progressive tense vs gerund). But I don't see what useful points can be made by contrasting the examples as given.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: No, I totally agree. I don't know what kind of mood that was I was in when I wrote that. Snarky optimism?

Comment: No, it's not a noun phrase.  The Photon's answer is correct; it's headlinese, in which forms of **be** are usually omitted.

Comment: @snailboat: Granted it's *possible* to see #2 as "normal" in the context of a newspaper headline. But following OP's edit it's clear that wasn't his intention. Personally I think the original question should remain closed (with existing perfectly adequate answers), and OP should post the rephrased version as a new question. I'll [raise the issue on meta](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/777/).

Comment: Hi Arun, welcome to ELL! Your edit was a good one, and I appreciate the effort. However it does fundamentally change this question, which already has answers. I've rolled this question back to the revision which corresponds with these answers, but you're more than welcome to post a *new* question which asks what you really wanted to know. Then that question can get the answers you want! You can find the text you typed up for the edit in this question's [revision history](http://ell.stackexchange.com/posts/10135/revisions). Thanks!

Comment: @FumbleFingers +1.  I've re-read the question after reading your comment, and I think I see what's going on.  It seems to me that the OP wants to use a construction from a headline in normal English, where it would be interpreted as you say, and that they're making this mistake because they don't realize headlines have their own peculiar grammar.

Comment: @snailboat: In truth, I hadn't registered the "headlinese" interpretation of OP's example #2 when I made my first comment. I may be wrong, but I'd have thought the grammar of most if not *all* languages is considerably relaxed in the context of newspaper headlines, billboards, etc. They're trying to *catch your attention*, not teach you grammar.

Answer (score 3):

The second example looks like it comes from the headline of a newspaper article rather than from the body.

Newspaper headlines use a very abbreviated style intenteded to convey maximum information with a minimum number of words. They don't necessarily follow the rules for ordinary prose. In this case, I think Howard's answer gives the correct interpretation. They've omitted the "are" from

> Pregnant women are continuing to drink alcohol despite warnings

Some of the common conventions of newspaper headline writing are covered [here](http://chronicle.com/blogs/linguafranca/2013/02/18/the-grammar-of-newspaper-headlines/).

Comment: good point re news +1 vote from me :)) News, tech, and, most notoriously, business English tend to mangle the language... "News writers drinking on the job finding cigarette breaks short."  (ouch cliche :-P )

Answer (score 0):

As the first two comments mention, the question is too broad in scope. But some clarifications and variations might continue to help. :))

1.

- In July exports declined. [Simple, direct - but changes the meaning as it's up to the reader to know if the decline continued from before.]

These are progressively worse for many reasons:

- In July exports continued declining.  [a bit sloppy]
- In July exports continued their decline. [*their* is redundant]
- Continuing their decline, exports went down again in July. [verbose]

2.

- Pregnant women continuing to drink alcohol despite warnings from medical experts ... [incomplete sentence fragment]

Since that's a fragment, we can only guess what the rest might need. So the meaning changes depending:

- Pregnant women, who continue drinking alcohol despite warnings from medical experts, are at higher risk for  (whatever).  [Clean, clear]
- Pregnant women **are** continuing *to drink* alcohol despite warnings from medical experts. [Progressive form. In the present, still 'happening'. Every pregnant women is drinking during pregnancy - we have a public health crisis!]
- Pregnant women **have continued** to drink alcohol despite warnings from medical experts. [Present, statement of fact - it's still a problem, but using Present over Progressive makes it feel more formal, less immediate. This is subtle. I think 'continued drinking' would also be common.]

So in summary, let's rephrase the two example sentences you gave.

> In July exports of goods continued to decline.

Becomes:

> In July exports of goods were still on the decline.

[The were, and still are, declining. They *continue* the previous decline.]

> Pregnant women continuing to drink alcohol despite warnings ...

Let's say a reasonable guess is ...

> Drinking alcohol *during* pregnancy causes problems. If you don't listen to the warnings, then ...
>
> Pregnant women continuing to drink alcohol despite warnings need to have their heads examined.

" women continuing to drink alcohol despite warnings" is a noun phrase, which shortens to:  "They need to have their heads examined."